# Error compiling mfc program with vs2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mfc

I am searching for a long time on internet. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. When I wrote the mfc program with vs2015, I derived a class (CMainView) from CListView. When I added the NM_DBLCLK message in the derived class, VS2015 smart prompt

> "There is extra text after the expected end of the number"

But it can be compiled successfully.I don’t understand why.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainView, CListView)
  ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_ADD, &CMainView::OnEditAdd)
  ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_DEL, &CMainView::OnEditDel)
  ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_MOD, &CMainView::OnEditMod)
  ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(NM_DBLCLK, &CMainView:OnNMDblclk) //error code 
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Comment: please post some code !

Comment: all the relevant information should be in the question, plus comments are not formatted and hence hard to read, so please edit the question.

Comment: Show the declaration of `CMainView:OnNMDblclk`. Does it compile if you remove the line `ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(NM_DBLCLK, &CMainView:OnNMDblclk)`?

Comment: void CMainView::OnNMDblclk(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
 LPNMITEMACTIVATE pNMItemActivate = reinterpret_cast<LPNMITEMACTIVATE>(pNMHDR);
 OnEditMod();
 *pResult = 0;
}

Comment: if I remove the line ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(NM_DBLCLK, &CMainView:OnNMDblclk),It can compile, but double click no message response.

Comment: You put `:` instead of `::`, change to `&CMainView::OnNMDblclk`

Comment: sorry,The wrong code was actually generated automatically by vs2015 and I got it wrong